# Automatically assign a jira issue once dev complete status is set?

Tags: jira

Is it possible to automatically assign an issue in jira to a tester once the developer has marked it as dev complete?

Sometimes the dev forgets to assign the completed issue to the tester so I wanted to know if it was possible to auto assign it once dev is complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Post Function option called "Assign to role member". Then you can choose a Project Role, and set conditions.

I don't remember if it is a built-in feature or if you need the [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin.